# Xamarin.Android Conflict between assemblies

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, zxing

I'am facing a ridiculous issue on Xamarin.Android.
I'am replacing the basic Actionbar by a Toolbar in my App. I want to support from Android 4.0.4 to newer Android versions. So i installed with Nuget packages (Visual studio) this package:

**Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** which install this package too: **Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment**

Well it's ok but i use this package in order to scan Qrcodes and Barcodes: **ZXing.Net.Mobile**

Error:

*FragmentStatePagerAdapter exists in 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

So i decided to remove one of them but **ZXing.Net.Mobile** use **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** use **Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment**.

Is there a solution for this kind of issue ?

Thank you !

Solution:

**Install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 23.4.0.1 and upgrade when Zxing retarget packages. 2.4.0.1 = July 2016 < September 2016 (Package split, explained in first answer)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `ZXing.Net.Mobile` will need to retarget and use the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment` package as the `v4` package has been split into multiple packages:

> With this release, the v4 Support Library has been split into several smaller modules:
>
> - support-compat
> - support-core-utils
> - support-core-ui
> - support-media-compat
> - support-fragment

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html